# php 5.5 text area input filtering & output escaping

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, sanitization

From researching the best way to sanitize HTML form data, I have found that you should "FILTER INPUT" and "ESCAPE OUTPUT."

Unfortunately most of the info on this subject that out there is old information (PHP 4.x, 2009, etc.). Many web pages recommend `mysql_real_escape_string` which is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

I am on PHP 5.5.x, Apache web server, and a MySQL database. I am using PDO prepared statements. All character sets are UTF-8.

I have looked at the PHP Sanitize filters (found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

I have filtered all inputs and escaped all outputs except for my textareas. The text areas are for the user to "describe an event." These are fairly large at 500 characters. This is the one spot that I feel most vulnerable to malicious code.

The first thing that I do to all input is the `trim()` function.

What are the best filters to run on input?

How should I be escaping output?

I want the output to be readable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends on your needs. Do you save text area input in DB, text files other? Do you want display it as plain text, HTML or use own "codes" system like BBCode?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends about the input kind you want to filter.
Let's assume you want to only simple plain text in your textarea, so you need to avoid javascript, css and html code also you need to prevent SQL Injection in this input and get only 500 characters of length.

1. Use **strip_tags** to avoid HTML, CSS and JS tags.
2. Use **str_replace**("'","\'", $string)  to prevent SQL Injection parsing
   single quote.
3. Use **substr** to cut the string in 500 characteres if the
   are more than the limit.

I recommend you visit :
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Also I recommend use a PHP Framework to avoid the tradicional way in you work with this common security risks.

In my opinion you can use Zend, Code Igniter or Laravel.

1. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html
2. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.filter.html
3. http://laravel.com/docs/validation